# Permutation generator on C

Tags: c, algorithm

I need a simple Algorithm of permutation generator which could be apply on simple C language.

Comment: Then why is the question marked C++? in C++ you can use std::next_permutation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any better methods to do permutation of string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995328/are-there-any-better-methods-to-do-permutation-of-string)

Comment: Besides that, you can always check the sources of STL's next_permutation, algorithm isn't so difficult.

Answer (score 7):

Permutes over numbers:

In order to do use each permutation, you have to hook up to the print function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
   Read a number, N, from standard input and print the
   permutations.
 */

void print(const int *v, const int size)
{
  if (v != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      printf("%4d", v[i] );
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
} // print


void swap(int *v, const int i, const int j)
{
  int t;
  t = v[i];
  v[i] = v[j];
  v[j] = t;
}


void rotateLeft(int *v, const int start, const int n)
{
  int tmp = v[start];
  for (int i = start; i < n-1; i++) {
    v[i] = v[i+1];
  }
  v[n-1] = tmp;
} // rotateLeft


void permute(int *v, const int start, const int n)
{
  print(v, n);
  if (start < n) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = n-2; i >= start; i--) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
    swap(v, i, j);
    permute(v, i+1, n);
      } // for j
      rotateLeft(v, i, n);
    } // for i
  }
} // permute


void init(int *v, int N)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    v[i] = i+1;
  }
} // init


int main()
{
    int *v = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    init(v, 10);
    permute(v, 0, 10);
    free(v);
}
```

Comment: This is C++ code, not C. However, it can be easily transformed to C code: `s/new int[10]/malloc(10*sizeof(int))/` and `s/delete [] v/free(v)/`

Comment: Is there any reference to literature to assert this algorithm is correct? E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm (which this solution is not)

Answer (score 3):

all

I found algorithms to generate permutations in lexicographic order from The Art of Computer Programming (TAOCP):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

**Generation in lexicographic order**
There are many ways to systematically generate all permutations of a given sequence[citation needed]. One classical algorithm, which is both simple and flexible, is based on finding the next permutation in lexicographic ordering, if it exists. It can handle repeated values, for which case it generates the distinct multiset permutations each once. Even for ordinary permutations it is significantly more efficient than generating values for the Lehmer code in lexicographic order (possibly using the factorial number system) and converting those to permutations. To use it, one starts by sorting the sequence in (weakly) increasing order (which gives its lexicographically minimal permutation), and then repeats advancing to the next permutation as long as one is found. The method goes back to Narayana Pandita in 14th century India, and has been frequently rediscovered ever since.

The following algorithm generates the next permutation lexicographically after a given permutation. It changes the given permutation in-place.

1. Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
2. Find the largest index l such that a[k] < a[l]. Since k + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies k < l.
3. Swap a[k] with a[l].
4. Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

After step 1, one knows that all of the elements strictly after position k form a weakly decreasing sequence, so no permutation of these elements will make it advance in lexicographic order; to advance one must increase a[k]. Step 2 finds the smallest value a[l] to replace a[k] by, and swapping them in step 3 leaves the sequence after position k in weakly decreasing order. Reversing this sequence in step 4 then produces its lexicographically minimal permutation, and the lexicographic successor of the initial state for the whole sequence

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic algorithm found (among other places) in Knuth's TAOCP.

Here's an example I used for a project euler problem.  It creates all the permutations of a string in lexicographical order and prints them to stdout.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char set[10]="0123456789";
        char scratch;
        int lastpermutation = 0;
        int i, j, k, l;
        printf("%s\n",set);
        while (!lastpermutation)
        {
                //find largest j such that set[j] < set[j+1]; if no such j then done
                j = -1;
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                        if (set[i+1] > set[i])
                        {
                                j = i;
                        }
                }
                if (j == -1)
                {
                        lastpermutation = 1;
                }
                if (!lastpermutation)
                {
                        for (i = j+1; i < 10; i++)
                        {
                                if (set[i] > set[j])
                                {
                                        l = i;
                                }
                        }
                        scratch = set[j];
                        set[j] = set[l];
                        set[l] = scratch;
                        //reverse j+1 to end
                        k = (9-j)/2; // number of pairs to swap
                        for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
                        {
                                scratch = set[j+1+i];
                                set[j+1+i] = set[9-i];
                                set[9-i] = scratch;
                        }
                        printf("%s\n",set);
             }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple recursive solution to produce all permutations of a set of characters passed on the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int perm(const char *src, int len, char *dest, char *destbits, int n) {
    if (n == len) {
        printf("%.*s\n", len, dest);
        return 1;
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (destbits[i] == 0) {
                destbits[i] = 1;
                dest[n] = src[i];
                count += perm(src, len, dest, destbits, n + 1);
                destbits[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *src = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "123456789";
    int len = strlen(src);
    char dest[len], destbits[len];

    memset(destbits, 0, sizeof destbits);
    int total = perm(src, len, dest, destbits, 0);
    printf("%d combinations\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for something more iteractive, then I implement my poor version. I can see some optimizations, but for now it's helps me. I hope this helps anyone.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PERM_T int
#define PERM_T_PFLAG "%d"

void swap(PERM_T *array, int i, int j) {
  PERM_T aux = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = aux;
}

void print_array_perm(PERM_T *array, int n) {
  printf("[");
  n -= 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf(PERM_T_PFLAG", ", array[i]);
  }
  if (n >= 0)
    printf(PERM_T_PFLAG, array[n]);
  printf("]\n");
}

void print_array_int(int *array, int n) {
  printf("[");
  n -= 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", array[i]);
  }
  if (n >= 0)
    printf("%d", array[n]);
  printf("]\n");
}

void copy_array_T(
  PERM_T *src, PERM_T *dst,
  int start, int end) {
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    dst[i] = src[i];
  }
}

void copy_array_int(
  int *src, int *dst,
  int start, int end) {
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    dst[i] = src[i];
  }
}

void rotate_array(
  PERM_T *array,
  int start, int end) {
  PERM_T aux = array[start];
  copy_array_T(
    array + 1, array, start, end);
  array[end - 1] = aux;
}

int factorial(int n) {
  int result = 1;
  while (n > 1) {
    result *= n;
    n--;
  }
  return result;
}

typedef struct {
  PERM_T *data;
  int length;
  int *ks;
  int kn;
  int _i;
} Perm;

Perm perm_(
  PERM_T *data, PERM_T *array, int n) {
  copy_array_T(array, data, 0, n);
  int kn = n > 1 ? n - 1 : 0;
  
  int *ks = kn
    ? malloc(sizeof(PERM_T) * kn)
    : NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < kn; i++)
    ks[i] = i;

  int max_iterations = factorial(n);
  Perm p = {
    .data = data,
    .length = n,
    .ks = ks,
    .kn = kn,
    ._i = max_iterations
  };
  return p;
}

Perm perm(PERM_T *array, int n) {
  PERM_T *data = 
    malloc(sizeof(PERM_T) * n);
  return perm_(data, array, n);
}

Perm copy_perm(Perm p) {
  Perm copy = perm(p.data, p.length);
  copy_array_int(p.ks, copy.ks, 0, p.kn);
  return copy;
}

void clear_perm(Perm* p) {
  free(p->data);
  if (p->kn) free(p->ks);
}

int completed_perm(Perm *p) {
  return p->_i < 1;
}

void next_perm_self(Perm *p) {
  int n = p->length;

  if (completed_perm(p)) return;

  p->_i--;
  int k = p->kn - 1;
  int *ks = p->ks;
  PERM_T *data = p->data;

  if (ks[k] + 1 != n) {
    rotate_array(data, k, n);
    ks[k] += 1;
  } else {
    while (k >= 0 && ks[k] + 1 == n) {
      ks[k] = k;
      rotate_array(data, k, n);
      k -= 1;
    }
    if (k >= 0) {
      rotate_array(data, k, n);
      ks[k] += 1;
    }
  }
}

Perm next_perm_(Perm *p) {
  Perm next = copy_perm(*p);
  next_perm_self(&next);
  return next;
}

Perm next_perm(Perm *p) {
  Perm next = next_perm_(p);
  clear_perm(p);
  return next;
}

void print_perm(Perm p) {
  print_array_perm(p.data, p.length);
}

void print_perm_(Perm p) {
  printf("%p\n", p.data);
  print_perm(p);
  print_array_int(p.ks, p.kn);
}

Perm next_print(Perm *p) {
  print_perm(p);
  return next_perm(p);
}

void next_print_self(Perm *p) {
  print_perm(*p);
  next_perm_self(p);
}

int main() {
  int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  Perm p = perm(a1, 5);
  
  int i = 0;
  while (!completed_perm(&p)) {
    printf("%3d ", i++);
    // p = next_print(&p);
    next_print_self(&p);
  }

  clear_perm(&p);
  return 0;
}
```