# Permutation of 0..7 in C

Tags: c, permutation

I'm trying to make a simple permuation program that, from an input numbers returns me all the permutations of the other numbers.

If I've:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

And I put as input number 3, I want to have all the permutations of every number except the given number. I dont care the order of the list, I just care the first number is the input number.

```
{3,0,1,2,4,5,6,7}
{3,1,2,4,5,6,7,0}
{3,2,4,5,6,7,0,1}
... etc
```

I've tryed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862191/permutation-generator-on-c), which gives all the permutation, but it start's from 1 and I dont know how to stop it when I finish showing the permutations of the "desired first number", as I dont care the rest ones. It would be also great to handle the outputs with indexes for another stuff I'm doing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: A less elegant solution can be to remove the number from array, show permutations of all other numbers and add that number to all those solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this program with your input number as the argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, x;
#define SWAP(i, j)  x = a[i], a[i] = a[j], a[j] = x

void print()
{
    int i;
    char c = '{';
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof a; c = ',') printf("%c%d", c, a[i++]);
    puts("}");
}

void perm(int j)
{
    int i = j-1, k;
    if (i <= 0) { print(); return; }

    perm(i);
    for (; i; --i)
    {
        for (k = j; k > i; --k)
            if (a[i] == a[k]) break;
        if (k > i) continue;

        SWAP(i, j);
        perm(j-1);
        SWAP(i, j);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    if (argc != 2) return 1;

    i = atoi(argv[1]);
    SWAP(i, 0);
    perm(sizeof a - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks great but, but I'm having problems trying to execute the program with an input number as an argument. Is there any chance you can change the code a bit so I can put in the main function directly the desired number?

The thing I tried for this is to put `i = 5;` (for example) but it's not working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, surely you can change `i = atoi(argv[1])` to `i = 5`; perhaps you just forgot to delete the line `if (argc != 2) return 1;`.