# The possible combinations of n digits

Tags: c

I want to write a C function that takes one integer as input and gives me all possible combinations using that much digits.

For example:

```
cases(3);
```

Output:

```
123 132 213 231 312 321
```

It uses the first three digits to create a three digit number, notice that I need that to work for any number of digits n.

Notice that cases(3) has 3! = 6 results.
So cases(4) has 4! = 24 results and so on.

I actually don't even know how to even approach this problem so any help is appreciated.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. We help you _fix_ code, not _write_ code. This means that we help you with your code when the _code_ has a problem. We don't write your algorithms for you.

Comment: Considering that the result is n! in size, it may take a while to print the results for n above 20 :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862191/permutation-generator-on-c

Comment: Have you written code?

Answer (score 1):

Recursion for the win :-)

- the combinations of 1 digit is `1`
- the combinations of `N` digits is the *recursive* combinations of `N - 1` digits with `N` added at every possible place

Answer (score 0):

try to think of an algorithmn before you actually try to write the code. 
Think of how you solved the Problem in your head when you wrote your desired output down. just find a systematic way to do this: for example you start with the lowest number and then check for the other numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I have written the logic and code in python

```
#n digit number as input converted into list
m=int(input("enter number of digits:"))
f=[]
for i in range(1,m+1):
    f.append(str(i))
#dynamic array for dynamic for loop inside recursion 
a=[0 for k in range(len(f))]

c=[]#list which is to be used for append for digits
ans=[]# result in which the 
# recursion for if loop inside for loop
#1st argument is fixed inside the loop
#2nd argument will be decreasing
def conditn(k,m):
    if(m==0):
        return 1
    if(m==1):
        if(a[k]!=a[0]):
            return 1
    if(a[k]!=a[m-1] and conditn(k,m-1)):
        return 1
#recursion for for loop
#1st argument y is the length of the number
#2nd argument is for initialization for the varible to be used in for loop
#3rd argument is passing the list c
def loop(y, n,c):


    if  n<y-1:
        #recursion until just befor the last for loop
        for a[n] in range(y):
            if(conditn(n,n)):

                loop(y, n + 1,c)


    else:
    # last for loop
        if(n==y-1):
            for a[n] in range(y):
            #last recursion of condition
                if(conditn(n,n)):
                #concatinating the individual number
                    concat=""
                    for i in range(y):
                        concat+=f[a[i]]+""
                    c.append(concat)

#returning the list of result for n digit number
    return c 
#printing the list of numbers after method call which has recursion within
#set is used used to convert any of the iterable to the
#distinct element and sorted sequence of iterable elements, 
for j in (loop(len(f),0,c)):
    print(j)
```