# Generate all possible permutations in C

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

I'm trying to develop a code to solve the Travelling salesman problem in C, but I have some restrictions: I can only use "for, "while", "do", arrays, matrix and simple things like that, so, no functions or recursion (unfortunately).

What I've got so far:

The user will will type the city coordinates X and Y like this:

```
8.15    1.58
9.06    9.71
1.27    9.57
9.13    4.85
```

The code to storage the coordinates.

```
float city[4][2];
int i;

for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    scanf("%f %f", &cidade[i][0], &cidade[i][1]);
```

There are 4 cities, so "i" goes from 0 to 3. X and Y are storaged on the second dimension of the matrix, [0] and [1].

The problem now is that I have to generate ALL POSSIBLE permutations of the first dimension of the matrix. It seems easy with just 4 cities, because all possible routes are (it must starts with city A everytime):

```
A B C D
A B D C
A C B D
A C D B
A D C B
A D B C
```

But I'll have to expand it for 10 cities. People have told me that it will use 9 nested foor loops, but I'm not being able to develop it =(

Can somebody give me an idea?

Comment: "No functions" ? That a very stupid constraint. And solving the Traveling Salesman problem by bruteforce is so as well.

Comment: How would you generate all 1-long combinations for 10 cities? A for-loop that just produced all cities. Now, for 2-long ones, it's a loop over 10 cities to get the first, for each "first" city a loop over the other cities to get the second of the combination. For 3 long, it's each of the 10 cities followed in each case by the 2-long combinations of the other cities.... and so on, up to 10

Comment: @EugeneSh, it's an assignment. The point is about writing the C, not solving the travelling salesman problem efficiently.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Writing C without functions?? How is that? Sometimes I am just wondering what these guys in schools are trying to teach.

Comment: Since you can't use recursion and functions, you can imitate recursion with a while loop and references to your current parent node. First figure out how you would do it with recursion, then try to translate that into using a while loop.

Comment: As an initial assignment, it's OK.  I'd agree one would quickly want to move on to allowing functions

Comment: Sorry guys, but what my professor is trying to do is to force us to develop complex For loops.

Comment: @Shofukan He should try to teach the exact opposite. Anyway, complete your course and stay away from this guy. And try not to follow his guidelines...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul But in this case I'd get all possible combinations of all the cities (A A A A... is a possible combination, for instance), but I want permutations (A B C D...).

Comment: No, that's why I said " a loop over the **other** cities"

Comment: No functions?  Just hand in a note saying that, with no main() function, you cannot solve the problem in C.

Comment: And get an `F` for being a smartass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending to 10 (and looking up city names) as an exercise for the reader. And it's horrid, but that's what you get with your professor's limitations

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for (int one = 0; one < 4; one++) {
        for (int two = 0; two < 4; two++) {
            if (two != one) {
                for (int three = 0; three < 4; three++) {
                    if (one != three && two != three) {
                        for (int four = 0; four < 4; four++)
                            if (one != four && two != four && three != four) {
                                printf("%d %d %d %d\n", one, two, three, four);
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the assignment will say "no functions in the body of main", or something or it's going to be an unanswerable assignment!

Comment: And, yes, `printf` is a function, but the real answer won't need `printf`. Although I do wonder how it will display the result!

Comment: Well, OK, horrid.  I would have gone with 'gruesome'.

Comment: "(informal)=  unpleasant, terrible, awful, offensive, nasty, disgusting, horrible, dreadful, obscene, disagreeable, yucky" (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/horrid). Yep, all of them apply.

Comment: I guess I expressed myself wrongly. I can use printf, scanf and etc. But I'm not allowed to create a new "int main(SOMETHING_HERE)". By the way, I'm a beginner, I don't even know how to do it, and it's hard for me to talk about a subject which I'm not yet familiar with in a foreign language, hehe.

Comment: But I found my mistake. I thought that when it reached the "printf" function for the first time it would go back to the first for (int one = 0...), but that's not how for loops work.

Comment: Thank you very much @TheArchetypalPaul for being patient. I've been programming for only 1 month and a half, but I'm trying to improve my almost non-existing-skill heheh.

Comment: No problem. Please make sure you understand the above before you submit it. Also, you might want to think about how to make the one piece of code work for any number of cities, by using functions and the idea that combinations of length n are each of the values  followed by all the combinations of length n-1 that don't use that value....

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Yeah, this is just the beginning of the code, I guess. Since you asked earlier, the code will generate all possible combinations, calculate the euclidian distance between the cities and display, through a printf function, the best route (shortest, i.e., cheapest).

Answer (score 0):

This is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3928241/5264491

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { num_perm = 10 };
    int perm[num_perm];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num_perm; i++) {
        perm[i] = i;
    }

    for (;;) {
        int j, k, l, tmp;

        for (i = 0; i < num_perm; i++) {
            printf("%d%c", perm[i],
                   (i == num_perm - 1 ? '\n' : ' '));
        }

        /*
         * Find largest j such that perm[j] < perm[j+1].
         * Break if no such j.
         */
        j = num_perm;
        for (i = 0; i < num_perm - 1; i++) {
            if (perm[i + 1] > perm[i]) {
                j = i;
            }
        }
        if (j == num_perm) {
            break;
        }

        for (i = j + 1; i < num_perm; i++) {
            if (perm[i] > perm[j]) {
                l = i;
            }
        }

        tmp = perm[j];
        perm[j] = perm[l];
        perm[l] = tmp;

        /* reverse j+1 to end */
        k = (num_perm - 1 - j) / 2; /* pairs to swap */
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            tmp = perm[j + 1 + i];
            perm[j + 1 + i] = perm[num_perm - 1 - i];
            perm[num_perm - 1 - i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```