# Easiest way to make 4 letters permutations in C

Tags: c

I need to write a function that returns something like this, given only "1234":

```
    char *permutations[] = {"1234","1324", "1342","1423","1432","2134",
                            "2143","2314","2341","2413","2431","3124","3142",
                            "3214","3241","3412","3421","4123","4132","4213",
                            "4231","4312","4321", "1243"};
```

I wrote "letters" in the title because I actually need those numbers to be characters. I have read various posts here, but all aff them are very complicated since they try to get permutations for an N letters string. I don't need that, I only need those combinations but  have no clue whatsoever about how to do this. I know I should tell what I tried, but I really do have nothing yet, since all codes I have tried inspiring at use concepts I am totally unfamiliar like backtracking and recursion. Is there a really 'easy' way to do this without using any libraries?
Hoping you will understand, I thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: If nothing else works you can always do it by [brute force](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37213036).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @RetiredNinja that was not intentional, I am sorry.

Comment: The "easy" _obvious_ way for a string with N is writing a set of N nested loops, each one skipping the indexes of the outer loops. You will use the index to access an array of chars containing the supported symbols. But it will grow very very slow for N big enough.

Comment: I'd like to have all possible numbers made with that digits, basically

Comment: @RobertoCaboni that would not be a problem, since it will always be those 4 digits.

Comment: But if it's always those 4 digits, you  already have all the combinations of them hard-coded, why bothering to generate them?

Comment: @bereal you are right, but I am not allowed to hard code them.

Comment: Try to implement the nested loops I described you, and come back with your code if you have any specific issue with it. You'll post the function, the `main` for testing it and the actual output you get.

Comment: I'll try my best. Thank you! @RobertoCaboni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example :

**A.** The first number has 4 possible values, we simply traverse them in the outer loop.

**B.** The same is done for the second at each pass of the outer loop, except that we avoid duplicating A so that loop has a length of 3.

**C.** The same for C whose the loop has a length of 2 because it avoids duplicating A and B.

**D.** The last value has a unique choice and we can find it this way : D =  10 - (A + B + C), where 10 =  1+2+3+4.

Each time a new D is found we collect the sequence of four numbers and that finally results in a sorted series of length 24.

```
static inline char increase(char c) { return (c - '0') % 4 + '1'; }
#define A seq[0]
#define B seq[1]
#define C seq[2]
#define D seq[3]

int main() 
{
    char seq[5] = { '0', '0', '0', '0', 0};
    char collector[24][5];
    char icollect = 0;
    //--- A
    for (char i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        A = increase(A);
        //---- B
        B = '0';
        for (char j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            B = increase(B);
            //---- C
            C = '0';
            if (B == A) B = increase(B);
            for (char k = 0; k<2; k++) {
                do { C = increase(C); } while (C == A || C == B);
                //---- D
                D = 10 - ((A - '0') + (B - '0') + (C - '0')) + '0';
                //Collects
                memcpy(collector[icollect++], seq, 5);
            }
        }
    }
    //Prints
    for (char i=0; i<24; i++) {
        printf("%s%c", collector[i], i && (i+1)%6==0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
}

/* printed
1234 1243 1324 1342 1423 1432
2134 2143 2314 2341 2413 2431
3124 3142 3214 3241 3412 3421
4123 4132 4213 4231 4312 4321
*/
```