# complexity of recursive string permutation function

Tags: algorithm, string, complexity-theory

From: [Are there any better methods to do permutation of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995328/are-there-any-better-methods-to-do-permutation-of-string)

what is the complexity of this function???

```
void permute(string elems, int mid, int end)
{
    static int count;
    if (mid == end) {
        cout << ++count << " : " << elems << endl;
        return ;
    }
    else {
    for (int i = mid; i <= end; i++) {
            swap(elems, mid, i);
            permute(elems, mid + 1, end);
            swap(elems, mid, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ignoring the print, the recurrence relation satisfied is

`T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(n)`

If `G(n) = T(n)/n!` we get

`G(n) = G(n-1) + O(1/(n-1)!)`

which gives `G(n) = Theta(1)`.

Thus `T(n) = Theta(n!)`.

Assuming that the print happens exactly `n!` times, we get the time complexity as

`Theta(n * n!)`

Comment: @rajyavardhan: Why is there an `O(n)` factor in the initial recurrence?

Comment: Because of the swap operations - each operation takes O(1) and that happens in a loop.

Comment: Is the space complexity also quadratic `O(n^2)` because the unique permutations stored in a Set would grow larger the greater the initial input?

Answer (score 8):

Without looking too deeply at your code, I think I can say with reasonable confidence that its complexity is O(n!). This is because any efficient procedure to enumerate all permutations of n distinct elements will have to iterate over each permutation. There are n! permutations, so the algorithm has to be at least O(n!).

Edit:

This is actually O(n*n!). Thanks to @templatetypedef for pointing this out.

Comment: I think you're forgetting the O(n!) times you're printing O(n) characters, which takes O(n x n!) time.

Comment: @templatetypedef: n*n!<(n+1)*n!, i.e. n*n!<(n+1)!. O((n+1)!) is the same as O(n!), the extra n does not matter.

Comment: @MAK- O(n!) != O((n+1)!).  It's true that anything that's O(n!) is also O((n+1)!), but the opposite doesn't hold.  A quick proof - (n+1)! = O((n+1)!) trivially.  Now suppose that (n+1)! = O(n!); then there must be some c, n0 such that for any n > n0, (n+1)! < c n!.  This would mean that for any n > n0, n < c, which is impossible for any constant c.

Answer (score 3):

```
long long O(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else 
       return 2 + n * O(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    //do something
    O(end - mid);
}
```

This will calculate complexity of the algorithm.

Actualy O(N) is `N!!! = 1 * 3 * 6 * ... * 3N`