# Analyzing an exponential recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to calculate the complexity of the following
exponential recursive function.

The isMember() and isNotComputed() functions reduce the number
of recursive calls.

The output of this code is a set of A[], B[] which are printed at the 
initial part of recursive function call.

Would appreciate any inputs on developing a recursive relationship for this
problem which would lead to the analysis of this program.

Without the functions isMember(), isNotComputed() this code has the complexity of O(2^N).  Empirically (with the above two functions) this code has a complexity of O(|N^2||L|).  Where L is the number of recursive calls made, i.e. results generated.

I am trying to calculate the complexity of this code as accurate as possible, so that I can compare the efficiency of this with a set of other algorithms which are similar in nature.

```
void RecuriveCall(int A[], int ASize, short int B[], int BSize, 
              int y, short int level) { 
    int C[OBJECTSIZE]; 
    short int D[ATTRIBUTESIZE]; 
    int CSize, DSize; 
    PrintResult( A,ASize, B, BSize);                                                                         
    for (int j=y; j<n; j++) {                                                  
        if (! isMember(j, B, BSize)) {                                      
            function1(C,CSize,A,ASize,j);                             
            function2(D,DSize,C, CSize);                                 
            if (isNotComputed(B, BSize, D, DSize, j)) {                                                                                     
                RecursiveCall(C, CSize,D, DSize, j+1, level+1); 
            }      

        } 
    } 

}    

// Complexity - O(log N) - Binary Search
bool isMember(int j,short int B[], int BSize) { 
    int first, mid, last; 
    first = 0; 
    last = BSize-1; 

    if (B[first] == j || B[last] == j) { 
        return true; 
    } 

    mid = (first+last)/2; 
    while (first <= last) { 
        if (j == B[mid]) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        else if (j < B[mid])  
            last = mid-1; 
        else
            first = mid+1; 
        mid = (first+last)/2; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
// complexity - O(N)
bool isNotComputed(short int B[], int BSize, short int D[], int DSize,int j) { 
    if (j==0) { 
        return true; 
    } 

    int r = 0; 
    while (r<BSize && B[r]<j && r<DSize && D[r]<j) { 
        if (B[r] != D[r]) { 
            return false; 
        } 
        r=r+1; 
    } 
    // Now we can check if either B[] or D[] has extra elements which are < j 
    if (r<BSize && r < DSize && B[r]>=j && D[r] >=j) {// we know it is okay 
        return true; 
    } 
    if (r==BSize && r==DSize) {  
        return true; 
    } 
    if (r==BSize && r<DSize && D[r] >=j) {  
        return true; 
    } 
    if (r==DSize && r<BSize && B[r] >=j) { 
        return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
} 


// Complexity - O(N)
void function1(int C[],int &CSize,int A[] ,int ASize,int j) { 
    int tsize = 0; 
    for (int r=0;r<ASize;r++) 
        if (I[A[r]][j]==1) 
            C[tsize++] = A[r]; 
    CSize = tsize; 
} 

// Complexity - O(|N||G|) - G - number of objects
void function2(short int B[], int &BSize,int A[], int ASize) { 
   int i,j; 
   int c=0; 
    // Iterate through all attributes 
   for (j = 0; j < MAXATTRIBUTES; ++j) { 
      // Iterate through all objects 
      for (i = 0; i < ASize; ++i)  
         if (!I[A[i]][j]) 
            break; 
      if (i == ASize)  
         B[c++] = j; 
   } 
   BSize = c; 
}

void main() {
   n = MAXATTRIBUTES;
   for (int r=0; r<MAXOBJECTS; r++) 
       A[r] = r; 
   ASize = MAXOBJECTS; 
   function2(B, BSize, A, ASize); 

   RecursiveCall(A, ASize,B, BSize, 0, 0); 
}
```

The answer presented by "mohamed ennahdi el idrissi" addresses how a recursive relationship can be developed.

How do you incorporate the functions isMember() and isNotComputed() functions into this.  In essence these reduce the number of recursive calls made significantly.  Is there a way of introducing a probabilistic function to represent them? i.e P(f(n))xRecCall(n-1).   I have seen the complexity of some algorithms been computed e.g. as O(N^2.48).  How do you come with such values?

Comment: What have you thought of? Where did it fail/work?

Comment: Could you provide the source for isMember and isNotComputed? We can assume function1 and function2 are O(1), but the result of the former functions are crucial to understand the overall complexity.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. If I ignore the isMember() and isNotComputed() methods the complexity of the code is O(2^N).  However in practice this algorithm runs at O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks Juan.  I have included the code for the other functions.  Appreciate any inputs.  By the way the algorithm computes formal concepts (Formal Concept Analysis).

Comment: What is `n` in `for (int j=y; j<n; j++)`? `n` is undetermined.

Comment: Thanks.  n = MAXATTRIBUTES;  I have updated the code, its used as a global variable, which is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to adapt the following recurrence relation to your code, see the steps below:

[image]
[image]

Where `n = MAXATTRIBUTES` (constant), and `m = ASize`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will go through your solution.

Comment: Hi Ennnahdi,  Just a quick check. Even if we ignore the function1() and function2() wouldn't the time complexity be O(2^N) or O(N!).  See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363619/complexity-of-recursive-string-permutation-function

Comment: Hi, shouldn't , TRecCall(y+1) be inside the sigma in the first line of the solution.

Comment: You're right, it should be inside the sigma, but it should be multiplied by some probability function, since it is executed under two conditions. For the earlier question, I need to recompute to assert it is O(2^N) or O(N!).