# Can a probabilty function be used as part of calculating the complexity of a code

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, code-analysis, analysis, code-complexity

How can you incorporate a probability function as part of complexity analysis of code.

```
if (cond1(l,n)) {
   for (int r=l;r<n;r++)
      for (int m=r;m<n;m++)
          for (int k=m;k<n;k++)
               //calculation
} else
    // calculation
```

A typical complexity analysis of this code would produce the complexity as O(N^3).

Assume that cond1(l,n) significantly produces false hence skips the inner for loops in a hypothetical calculation.

I would like to calculate the complexity of the code accurately as possible because I want to compare the complexity of a series of similar algorithms.

For example I want to replace cond1(l,n) with different set of algorithms that reduce the inner loop call.

How can I calculate the complexity of algorithm as accurate as possible.

A realistic scenario of the code that I am trying to analyse is at [link] [Analyzing an exponential recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468916/analyzing-an-exponential-recursive-function)

Answer (score 0):

Complexity analysis isn't the right tool for the job here: it's intended to give a rough idea of what happens as the size of the problem scales.  If you're looking for precise analysis of runtime, you want to benchmark or profile your code instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  The problem that I have mentioned in [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468916/analyzing-an-exponential-recursive-function actually has a complexity of O(|2^N||L|) or O(|N!||L|).  However the actual complexity is O(|N^2||L|) empirically, where the function similar cond1() reduces the recursive calls significantly.   Is there a way to take it into account when you calculate the theoretical running time of the algorithm?

Comment: Maybe you should consider best case, average case, and worst scenarios; just like sorting algorithms are analyzed.
I tried to solve your algorithm (in the link), but I think you should decompose your algorithm as such. You should be able to run it ... Sample it to deduce its performance based on inputs.