# recursion - all permuations of a string

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, permutation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any better methods to do permutation of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995328/are-there-any-better-methods-to-do-permutation-of-string)

I know recursion and can write programs like `fibonacci number`, `tree traversals` so I think I know it but when it comes to this question specifically I feel bad

Please guide me with how to calculate all possible permutations of a string

Comment: follow my guide: write the title in the SO search box.

Comment: <emphasis> What have you tried? </emphasis>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is good examples of different permutation algorithms, including recursive one: http://www.bearcave.com/random_hacks/permute.html