# How to get every possible pattern of an array of letters

Tags: c#, javascript, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any better methods to do permutation of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995328/are-there-any-better-methods-to-do-permutation-of-string)

Lets say I have the letters

> a b c d

and I want to get every single possible pattern/combination of these letters in a string that is 4 letters long.

> aaaa
>
> baaa
>
> caaa
>
> daaa
>
> abaa
>
> acaa
>
> acad
>
> abba

and so on.

What loop or pattern can I use to list every combination possible?

I am writing this in C#, but examples in C++ and javascript are welcome as well.

My current idea only increments one letter for each letter possible. Then shifts to the right once and repeats. This doesn't cover patterns like.

> abba

Comment: Is it always 4 letters?  If so it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: @liho1eye posting two for loops is pointless since it is not the correct solution.

@ james no, it can be more than 4 letters and its length can be more than 4 letters so dynamic on both parts.

@ brian do you have anything better to do than search up old postings and post wikipedia links :T

Comment: This isn't quite the same problem as permutation.  Permutations of { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' } would not include the string "aaaa".

Comment: @John - generally it's helping people with simple problems like this. I actually misread your question thinking you were looking for permutations as that's a common homework question to get posted here. I apologize - I didn't realize you were having a problem simply counting in what amounts to base4.

Comment: @John, do you need all of these permutations or could you simply get by with a `RegEx` to verify that the text you received is in the correct format?

Comment: Every possible combination, its not a validator.

Comment: combinations with repetitions.

Answer (score 50):

You can do so very easily with LINQ:

```
string[] items = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
var query = from i1 in items
            from i2 in items
            from i3 in items
            from i4 in items
            select i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;

foreach(var result in query)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If you don't know ahead of time that you want the combinations of four, you can compute arbitrary Cartesian Products with a bit more work:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

Comment: I could modify in 10 secs this in order to get n combinations. This is fantastic, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one with only one for loop

```
var one = ['a','b','c','d'];
var length = one.length;
var total = Math.pow(length, length);
var pow3 = Math.pow(length,3);
var pow2 = Math.pow(length,2);

for(var i = 0; i<total; i++)
    console.log(one[Math.floor(i/pow3)], 
        one[Math.floor(i/pow2)%length], 
        one[Math.floor(i/length)%length], 
        one[i%length]);
```

---

Here's a simple inefficient method:

```
var one = ['a','b','c','d'];
var i,j,k,l;
var len = 4;
for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
        for(k = 0; k < len; k++) {
            for(l = 0; l<len; l++) {
                console.log(one[i], one[j], one[k], one[l]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similar C#:

```
        var one = new[] {'a','b','c','d'};
        var len = one.Length;

        for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
            for(var j=0;j<len;j++) {
                for(var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                    for(var l = 0; l<len; l++) {
                        Console.Write(one[i] +  one[j] + one[k] +  one[l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this could be accomplished just using one array and reference different indexes.

Comment: You don't really need 4 arrays for that?

Comment: Interesting, seems to work I'll just need to clean it up

Answer (score 3):

Just for the heck of it, here's a generic solution for any number of letters in javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/U9ZkX/

Interestingly, google chrome would like to translate the output from "Malay".

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var letterCount = letters.length;
var iterations = Math.pow(letterCount, letterCount);

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    var word = "";

    for (var j = 0; j < letterCount; j++) {
        word += letters[Math.floor(i / Math.pow(letterCount, j)) % letterCount];
    }

    document.write(word + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A recursive C# implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<string> CreateCombinations(IEnumerable<char> input, int length)
{
    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (length == 1)
            yield return c.ToString();
        else 
        {
            foreach (var s in CreateCombinations(input, length - 1))
                yield return c.ToString() + s;
        }
    }
}
```

Should allow for any number of characters and any required string length (well until the stack overflows :))

Using it:

```
foreach (var s in CreateCombinations("abcd", 4))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Results in:

```
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
aaba
aabb
aabc
aabd
aaca
...
dddd
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I'd pick.  It's easily parameterised over the number of sets in the Cartesian product.  None of those ugly copy-and-pasted for loops. :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. @ChrisWue - Can you help me understand what this is doing? I need the same functionality in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this javascript solution using recursion. anyway not really expensive with these constraints (only 4^4 calls)

```
(function() {
   var combinations = [];

   (function r(s) {
       s = s || '';
       if (s.length === 4) {
          combinations[combinations.length] = s;
          return;
       }
       r(s + 'a');
       r(s + 'b');
       r(s + 'c');
       r(s + 'd');

   })();

   console.log(combinations);
})();
```

The output is

```
["aaaa", "aaab", "aaac", "aaad",...., "dddc", "dddd"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work, too ;)

```
var letters = new[] {'a','b','c','d'};
Random random = new Random();
HashSet<string> results = new HashSet<string>();

while(results.Count < 256) {
    results.Add(letters[random.Next(4)] + letters[random.Next(4)]
              + letters[random.Next(4)] + letters[random.Next(4)]);
}

results.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner in LINQ for any given n:

```
        var letters = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
        int n = 4;

        var z = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
            .Select(x => letters.AsEnumerable())
            .Aggregate((g,h) => g.Join(h, _ => true, _ => true, (a, b) => a + b));
```

Comment: i edited int n = 4; to n = letters.length;

Answer (score 1):

You have an alphabet with 2<sup>2</sup> letters, so every letter expresses exactly two bits, and thus for letters express eight bits. Now it's a simple matter of enumerating all values. In pCeudocode:

```
static const char alphabet[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 256; ++i)
{
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k != 4; ++k)
    {
        print(alphabet[(i >> (2*k)) % 4]);
    }
}
```

Here 256 = 2<sup>2 × 4</sup>, so you can easily generalize this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, straightforward javascript solution (season with braces to taste):

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], len=letters.length;

for (var i=len; i--;) 
  for (var j=len; j--;) 
    for (var k=len; k--;) 
      for (var l=len; l--;) 
        console.log (letters[i] + letters[j] + letters[k] + letters[l]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Recursion, Action Delegate and Lambdas!!!  (just for fun)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<char> letters = new List<char>() { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
            List<string> words = new List<string>();
            Action<IEnumerable<char>, string, List<string>> recursiveLetter = null;

            recursiveLetter = (availLetters, word, newWords) =>
            {
                if (word.Length < availLetters.Count())
                {
                    availLetters.ToList()
                                .ForEach(currentletter => 
                                           recursiveLetter(availLetters, 
                                                           word + currentletter, 
                                                           newWords));
                }
                else
                {
                    newWords.Add(word);
                }
            };

            recursiveLetter(letters, string.Empty, words); // ALL THE MAGIC GO!

            words.ForEach(word => Console.WriteLine(word));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if he wants to print all combinations of length 5 of 3 or 4 letters?

Comment: Easily changeable, but not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define WORD_LEN 5
#define ALPHA_LEN 4

char alphabet[ALPHA_LEN] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
int w[WORD_LEN] = {};

void print_word() {
    int i;
    char s[WORD_LEN + 1];
    for(i = 0; i < WORD_LEN; i++) {
        s[i] = alphabet[w[i]];
    }
    s[WORD_LEN] = '\0';
    puts(s);
}

int increment_word() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < WORD_LEN; i++) {
        if(w[i] < ALPHA_LEN - 1) {
            w[i]++;
            return 1;
        } else {
            w[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    do {
        print_word();
    } while (increment_word());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Linq based answer:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
items.ForEach(i1 => 
  items.ForEach(i2 =>
    items.ForEach(i3 =>
      items.ForEach(i4 =>
        Console.WriteLine(i1 + i2 + i3 + i4)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haskell may well have the shortest program here:

```
sequence (replicate 4 "abcd")
```

`replicate 4 "abcd"` creates a list that repeats `"abcd"` four times.  `sequence` is a very general, polymorphic, moadic operation that has many uses, among which is generating cartesian products of lists of lists.

It may be possible to duplicate this solution in C# or other .NET languages. Eric Lippert's LINQ solution corresponds to this Haskell solution:

```
items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

query = do i1 <- items
           i2 <- items
           i3 <- items
           i4 <- items
           return (i1 ++ i2 ++ i3 ++ i4)
```

If you compare them, well, note that LINQ's `from ... in` was inspired by Haskell's `<-`, and LINQ's `select` is Haskell's `return`.

The relationship between the Haskell one-liner solution and the longer one can be brought out by writing our own definition of `sequence`:

```
sequence' [] = return []
sequence' (m:ms) = do x <- m
                      xs <- sequence' ms
                      return (x:xs)
```

In LINQ terms, the `sequence` function allows you to replace the repeated `from ix in items` statements with just a list of the lists from which to choose each item.

**EDIT:** a friend just beat me at one-lining this (well, one line except for the `import`):

```
import Control.Monad

replicateM 4 "abcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

items = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

print [a + b + c+ d 
       for a in items
       for b in items
       for c in items
       for d in items]

Answer (score 0):

There must be an erlang list comprehension

Something like

```
Value = "abcd".
[ [A] ++ [B] ++ [C] ++ [D] || A <- Value, B <- Value, C <- Value, D <- Value ].
```