# Sfuffle a string to produce unique string and bring back to original string?

Tags: php, algorithm

is there any algo which shuffles characters of a string such that every shuffles return a unique combination, yet can be shuffled back to the original string if we know how many time it was shuffled?

this is what i have so far, yet it s not what i wanted. It can shuffle only (n/2)+1 times after that it comes back to the original string

```
//scramble data systematicslly
function Scramble($contents)
{
    $fsize=strlen($contents);
    $m=intval($fsize/2);
    $buffer=$contents[$m];
    for($i = 1; $i < $fsize; $i++)
    { 
        if($i%2==0)
        {
            if($m+$i<=$fsize){$buffer.= $contents[$m+$i];}
            if($m-$i>=0){$buffer.= $contents[$m-$i];}
        }else
        {
            if($m+$i<=$fsize){$buffer.= $contents[$m+$i];}
            if($m-$i>=0){$buffer.= $contents[$m-$i];}
        }
    }    
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: How much "unique" you mean?

Comment: for `aaaaa` there is only one possible shuffle, what do you want the algorithm to do in this case?

Comment: @MightyPork, atleast half of the characters should be moved

Comment: @amit, thats an exception.

Comment: @NokImchen Where the exceptions span? what about `aaaaab`, there are only 6 different combinations for it.

Comment: @Geobits, thanks for the link, i'll try testing it :)

Comment: @Geobits after shuffling with  Fisher-Yates shuffle, can we bring back to the original string if we know the key used?

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer on that question shows how.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying generate each possible combination of characters once? Then possibly starting over again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2031708/1516296. Algorithm is in C++. I think it should do what you want.

Comment: @Geobits, ah, i was too in a hurry that i went to google instead, thanks a lot for point :) wish i could mark u as accepted answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Create a function that performs an operation. If you do this you know the process so to find the original string, create another function that takes an integer as a parameter, and do the opposite of your original function *n* times.